# What sort of database setup is used for an App Store or Google Play Store?

Tags: mysql, java, application-design

I'm trying to build a desktop App Store, and it's just a small project for demonstration purposes, I'll be using java to create the application. In essence it's just a mock App Store that stores information about customer & applications. Note: We will only be working with sample data, so no new data will be added.

Now there is the option to use the JDBC but we're a team of four people, and there is a question of how other team members will have access to the data.

The second option I have in my mind is to connect to an online MySQL database, which would require installing the MySQL connector.

There is the option of using an embedded database, so the database will move with the application, in a sense, at least that's what I think.

I'm completely new to the database scenario, and I would really much appreciate any rational guidance for what database setup I should consider.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for a demonstration and won't be deployed to any users, and embedded database, for example SQLite, is a good choice. Not that there's anything wrong with running a local or shared instance of PostgreSQL or MySQL, but it will be marginally more work to set up.

Comment: Okay, but how about when we’re developing the application, each team member would have to create a database on their machine and then manually input data to the database? And if we were to run the application on a remote machine, how would we go about it? Would we have to create a database in SQLite and add data? Or is there a way you can take the database with the application?

Comment: To avoid having to enter any data manually, you can have a common SQL file responsible for inserting this data, just like you would with the database migrations. You can also move the file itself where SQLite keeps all the data along with the application.

Comment: Yes, I’ve implemented an SQLite embedded database that travels with the Java Project, so it’s always accessible. And I decided to implement test data through a java class, if no data is found in the database, then it’ll populate the database.